# SQL Server Code to "sanitize" user input into workable data formats

Tags: sql-server, regex, user-input, sanitize

I'm creating a function in MS SQL Server which will allow report developers to take data from user-input fields and convert them into a workable data format.  99% of the time, the code I'm using, below, works.  However, users never fail to figure out some way to impossibly screw up the data they are supposed to enter (I work for a very large company with thousands of entry-level data-entry employees).

What I mainly struggle with is turning really bad user input such as '$1,00,000..411' into a workable DECIMAL format.  I'd like it to turn into '100000.41' (because that's the closest we're going to get to knowing what was going through the user's mind when he or she typed it), but the code I'm using, below, will only turn it into '100000..411'.

Here's the code I've got worked up so far.  It allows the report developer to choose what kind of data types he or she wants returned, and also allows for the passing of custom regex:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_FieldSanitizer
     (
     @String VARCHAR(250)
     ,@Datatype VARCHAR(250)
     )
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @Expression VARCHAR(10)
     SELECT
           @Expression =   CASE
                                WHEN @Datatype = '1' THEN '^0-9-'
                                WHEN @Datatype = '2' THEN '^0-9.-'
                                WHEN @Datatype = '3' THEN '^a-z'
                                WHEN @Datatype = '4' THEN '^a-z '
                                WHEN @Datatype = '5' THEN '^a-z ,'
                                WHEN @Datatype = '6' THEN '^a-z0-9'
                                WHEN @Datatype = '7' THEN '^a-z0-9 '
                                WHEN @Datatype = '8' THEN '^a-z0-9 ,'
                                ELSE @Datatype
                                END

     WHILE PATINDEX('%['+@Expression+']%',@String) > 0
           SET @String = STUFF(@String,PATINDEX('%['+@Expression+']%',@String),1,'')

     RETURN @String

END
```

Comment: Are you struggling with cutting the '1000...0.411' into '1000...0.41'? If so use the [ROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function. I am not sure I totally understand your goal. Do you wan't some general purpose wrapper where devs can pass regexes? Then what is the purpose of the wrapper?

Comment: How the users enter the data? If they are using an UI, can't you validate at UI level?

Comment: I think you don't want to clean at the database level, you want to REJECT any bad data at that layer. The user will probably never know that you've changed what they entered and your cleansing it may ultimately store bad/useless data. I agree with @FLICKER - The UI should seek to minimize the rejections the database provides. My 2¢

Comment: I don't disagree it should be done at the front end, however, I'm a DBA and don't have control over the front end of the SOR.  Instead, I'm stuck dealing with the bad data and trying my best to help data analysts deal with the data.  I've brought it up several times, and when you work for a gigantic company like mine (over 250k total employees), even small efforts like that would never get prioritized.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to simply answer your question and staying with how you want to do this, I'd suggest adding a check and replace the @String before you do your SELECT, something like this:

```
     DECLARE @Expression VARCHAR(10)
     IF @Datatype = '2'
         AND (SELECT LEN(@String) - LEN(REPLACE(@String,'.',''))) > 1
         SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'..','.')
     SELECT
           @Expression =   CASE
```

On a side note, your @Datatype is defined as VARCHAR(150) but you seem to be using numbers. If so, I'd alter it to be SMALLINT or TINYINT, but that's a different article (along with how you should usually avoid scalar functions).

Also, as long as you have to deal with free text, you'll constantly be adding these types of error handling clauses (users will find unique ways to break things), which is why it is best left at the UI level as suggested by FLICKER.

Comment: I defined some preset expressions the users can pass with just the use of 1-8, but they can also pass their own custom expressions in the event they want to weed out or include other types of data I didn't predefine.

Comment: Yes, I see 1-8 and the regex associated which is why I used your @Datatype = '2'. So does the above work for removing the duplicate period in a decimal?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, which is one of the biggest reasons why I created this thread.  I work in finance, and currency records are a significant portion of the data we house.  Lots of calculations are run on these currencies, and if they aren't in a proper format, the jobs will fail.  Right now, we do a ISNUMERIC check beforehand to prevent bad data from erroring out a job, but I don't like they we lose sight of those line items when we do.  I'm hoping I could take my function a step further and turn something like "$1,234..45 ." into a workable format.

Comment: So your question states: What I mainly struggle with is turning really bad user input such as '$1,00,000..411' into a workable DECIMAL format. The IF statement above does just that so I'm confused on what you are looking for.

Comment: That only addresses the very specific scenario of two decimals in a row, which was just an example.  It wouldn't address an issue if the string was something along the lines of '100.1.14'.  The more I consider what I'm looking for, the more I think it's probably not possible.